# Autowired Environment is null in @Configuration-annotated classes

Tags: spring

In this `@Configuration`-annotated class, the `@Autowired` `Environment` class is always null.

The code-sample below is taken directly from:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
 public class AppConfig {

     @Autowired
     Environment env;

     @Bean
     public TestBean testBean() {
         TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
         // some futher contitional stuff/checks etc. on the properties 
         String someProp = env.getProperty(...);
         if(someProp.equals(...)) {
             ...
         }
         return testBean;
     }
 }
```

If I make the class implement `EnvironmentAware` the `Environment` is set correctly (and my code works).

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
 public class AppConfig implements EnvironmentAware {

     Environment env;

     @Bean
     public TestBean testBean() {
         // ...
     }

     @Override
     public void setEnvironment(final Environment environment) {
         this.environment = environment;
     }
 }
```

Any thoughts why the @Autowired approach does not work in `@Configuration`-annotated classes as expected, since autowiring the `Environment` in other beans works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add `@Bean` annotation to `Environment` class, because if You want `@Autowired` class who is not signed as `@Bean` then it is impossible

Comment: I can autowire Environment in other beans, but not in Configuration-annotated classes as stated. Futhermore Bean on a variable ist not possible.

Comment: ok, maybe change `@Autowired` for `@Resource` and make it public ?

Comment: I also tried this approach. Didn't work. Only approach that works is implementing EnvironmentAware, but its kind of ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting values directly:

```
@Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:/com/myco/app.properties")
 public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${testbean.name}")
    private String testbeanName;

    @Bean
    public TestBean testBean() {
       TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
       testBean.setName(testbeanName);
       return testBean;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I need to do some futher contitional stuff/checks etc. on the properties values, so the @Value approach can't be applied in my case. I updated my question to make more precise. Thanks anyway.